# Slack API: How to list your bot applications?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to list the bots owned by any user through the slack api.  The list of applications owned by a user is missing from [user.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) and [user.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list).  Which [api method](https://api.slack.com/methods) could I use to list the applications any one user owns? Or vice versa if I have a bot application id how could I determine who owns said bot?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you are looking for is [`team.integrationLogs`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.integrationLogs).

> This method lists the integration activity logs for a team, including
>   when integrations are added, modified and removed. This method can
>   only be called by Admins.

You will have to parse through the log with all changes to get the current state, but this is the only endpoint with that kind of information.